# Attempting to start "Windows Driver Foundation" service gives "Error 31: A device attached to the system is not functioning."

Tags: windows, drivers

My laptop is having a problem with the Windows Driver Foundation service that I cannot seem to figure out.

Attempting to start "Windows Driver Foundation" service gives "Error 31: A device attached to the system is not functioning."

I've gone through every device in the Windows "Device Manager" and all of them are working fine.

The Event Manager doesn't show any additional information for the error.

Basically I cannot find any way to determine what driver or device is giving the "Windows Driver Foundation" a problem.

Googling for this error didn't turn up anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Charlie